# La phrase « Je m'en suis fait donner un(e) » est-elle correcte?

Tags: grammaire, auxiliaires

Est-ce que cette formulation de phrase est syntaxiquement correcte ?  Je l'entends souvent et elle me fait grincer des dents.  J'ai l'impression que la bonne formulation serait « On m'en a donné un(e) » mais je ne suis pas capable de dire pourquoi l'autre ne serait pas bonne.

Comment: Syntaxiquement, il n'y a aucun doute qu'elle soit correcte (c'est du même type que « Je me suis fait couper les cheveux. »), tu veux peut-être dire grammaticalement, que comme je ne sais pas ce que ça désigne précisément, je ne sais pas pourquoi ça serait imprécis ^_^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Techniquement, *je m'en suis fait donner une* me semble tout à fait correct.

C'est au niveau du sens que l'on peut s'interroger:
*Se faire (verbe) (quelque chose)*, c'est soit

- agir auprès d'un tiers pour que celui-ci fasse pour nous l'action spécifiée par le verbe et l'applique à la chose spécifiée. Exemple: *je me suis fait couper les cheveux*. Pour ce qui est de donner, *se faire donner quelque chose par quelqu'un*, dans ce cas, c'est *demander quelque chose à quelqu'un* sachant que celui-ci accepte et procède.
- ou subir l'action spécifiée par le verbe et appliquée à la chose spécifiée. Exemple: *je me suis fait forcer ma porte*. Pour ce qui est de donner, *se faire donner quelque chose par quelqu'un*, dans ce cas, c'est *recevoir quelque chose de quelqu'un* sachant que c'est ce quelqu'un qui est à l'origine de l'action.

Answer (score 3):

Je ne trouve pas cette formulation élégante. Pourtant, elle semble correcte grammaticalement. J'ai donc cherché un peu.

On la retrouve dans de vieux écrits, par exemple, [Voltaire](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltaire), *Questions sur les Miracles*

> Je me suis fait donner une déclaration par mon troupeau, comme quoi j'étais honnête homme.

Dans les usages récents, j'ai trouvé plusieurs références dans les ouvrages québecois. En français de France, c'est plus rare, mais pas inexistant. Par exemple, [Claude Nicolet](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Nicolet) *Histoire, nation, république*

> C'est pourquoi, je me suis fait donner en 1995 par François Fillon [...] une mission d'évaluation et de proposition sur la formation civique.

Par parenthèse, *je me suis fait donner* prend le sens familier de "donner quelqu'un à la police", et donc signifie *je me suis fait dénoncer*